# python: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python, qt, segmentation-fault

I have written a Qt application in python using PySide library. When i close it i get **Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

**Backtrace using gdb:**

```
(gdb) backtrace 
#0  0x00007ffff5d19c40 in QObject::staticMetaObject () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtCore.so.4
#1  0x00007ffff64c4bce in PySide::SignalManager::clear() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyside-python2.7.so.1.2
#2  0x00007ffff64d1f95 in PySide::destroyQCoreApplication() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyside-python2.7.so.1.2
#3  0x00007ffff64d2981 in PySide::runCleanupFunctions() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyside-python2.7.so.1.2
#4  0x00007ffff683ecc5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PySide/QtCore.so
#5  0x000000000052f936 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#6  0x000000000056d0aa in ?? ()
#7  0x00000000004da29f in PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords ()
#8  0x000000000042fa19 in Py_Finalize ()
#9  0x000000000042fb7c in Py_Exit ()
#10 0x000000000042fcb9 in ?? ()
#11 0x000000000042ec32 in PyErr_PrintEx ()
#12 0x000000000042f042 in ?? ()
#13 0x000000000046aa09 in Py_Main ()
#14 0x00007ffff7817ec5 in __libc_start_main (main=0x46ac3f <main>, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdf58, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdf48) at libc-start.c:287
#15 0x000000000057497e in _start ()
```

**Version:**

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
Python 2.7.6
Ubuntu 14.04
```

How i can solve this?

Comment: You did something, that is not allowed with Qt. Show your code!

Comment: @Daniel I can't show my code. Is there a way to get faulty line using gdb or some other tool?

Comment: try to simplify your code, until the error vanishes.

Comment: The error is almost certainly somewhere else in the code to where the coredump occurs. The coredump is happening in a highly used bit of library code. The most likely explanation is that elsewhere in your code you have played about with a Qt object and left it in an inconsistent state, but that the error is only exposed when Qt is trying to cleanup.

Answer (score 1):

If this question is still up-to-date, I had the same Problem and solved it today. 
In my case it was a problem by calling

```
destroy()
```

method of my widget directly. 
Since I had some threads left open it ran into a segfault.
As I read right now it is a better practice to emit the close event.

I did now also override the closeEvt() method and checked there if the there is stuff to do before closing the app

```
##
#  Closes the application
#  ...
def closeEvent(self, event):
    if self.canClose() # Exit the application
        event.accept() 
        logging.debug("Closed App clean")
    else:
        # Do stuff to close the application cleanly
        if canCloseNow:
            event.accept()
        else: 
            # Give user feedbackstuff like opening a save dialog 
            # or some other stuff...
            event.ignore()
```

I am aware that most possibly there are much more elegant procedures to do this but for me it worked quite well...